# How is a source of sound in air set up a sound wave in an elastic medium such as glass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acoustics, elasticity, resonance, vibrations

I asked a question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/365880/shape-distortion-of-a-wine-glass-under-resonance?noredirect=1#comment819352_365880) about breaking a wine glass by resonance. This brings me to another question.

How does the sound wave in the air set up an sound wave in the glass? In this case, one does not directly strike the glass to generate the elastic wave in it. So how is the wave set up in the glass?

Comment: Can I suggest you work your way upwards from a simplified shape, as you have picked a shape, the wine glass, which has many degreees of freedom, each with their own  contribution, and each  to be explained. If you started with say, how does a tuning fork affect another tuning fork, or a guitar string, it might be easier to follow the resonance process. I would guess a full picture of a wine glass' vibrations modes and patterns would involve numerical analysis.

Comment: @User171879 I that case, instead of a glass, I would like to know how to produce a wave in a string or a tuning fork without plucking or hitting it directly (note that to set up a wave in the glass medium it was not hit or plucked directly). Just by using another source of the sound wave to how is the sound wave set up the in a string or tuning fork.

Comment: -1. This is question #3 in your earlier question. You should not ask the same question twice.

Answer (score 1):

A sound in air is a pressure wave. When a sound wave propagates thru the air you get fluctuations in the air pressure. If the sound wave passes thru a glass, the pressure wave will produce a similar wave in the glass. The glass will experience a sudden change in air density as the wave passes.

Comment: The pressure variation is in the air. A pressure variation in the air can cause the glass to deform. The deformation of the glass causes the elastic restoring forces to come into play, and an elastic wave is set up in the medium. This is what I guess. Your answer doesn't explain how the wave is produced in the glass.

Comment: Yes - thanks.  I was trying to keep the answer short. I guess I made it too short. lol